# Targetting the style of an <a> tag inside a <ul>

Tags: css

I am trying to run this CSS:

```
.portfolio-carousel.title a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

On this HTML:

```
<ul class="portfolio-carousel">
    <li>
        <h4 class="title">
            <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
        </h4>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I'm nothing is changing and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, you need a space between the class-names to indicate ancestor-descendant relationship:

```
.portfolio-carousel .title a {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RwLgn/).

Your original CSS selector was looking for an `a` element that was a descendant of an ancestor with both classes `portfolio-carousel` *and* `title`, whereas you want an `a` element that is the descendant of a `.title` element itself the descendant of `.portfolio-carousel` element.

References:

- [CSS Selectors, Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).